# changing images in a responsive grid

Tags: jquery, image, grid, swap, packery

I'm looking to create a responsive grid with different sized images, something similar to http://packery.metafizzy.co/ but also have those images swap out. I've found things that change images the same size as squares but looking to swap out different sized elements. something similar to what instagram does.

http://instagram.com/universityofwesternsydney

Any jquery plugins like this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do this, since it can be done purely in CSS.

### Use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Bootstrap offers a [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to lay out the responsive design.

Also, it offers a way to hide/show elements (even images) at certain screen width's using it's [Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

If you prefer not using Bootstrap, then you can use the CSS [`@media{}`](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) query to show/hide certain elements at certain sizes--Bootstrap basically does this, but packages it up for easy access.  Fairly easy to do, and no javascript/jQuery needed.